# How to make tensorflow read tensor as whole and not per row?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

My input data has 4 features (in columns) and a variable sized number of rows. It is stored in a `numpy array`. Feeding in an array of shape `[?, 4]` should result in 1 single one_hot vector of depth `number_classes`, not one per row.

I have set up my network like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, number_features])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, number_classes])

layer1 = tf.layers.dense(x, neurons_no, tf.nn.relu)
layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1, neurons_no, tf.nn.relu)
output = tf.layers.dense(layer2, number_classes, tf.nn.softmax)
```

I have tried specifying shape `[1, number_classes]` as shape for `y`, but it throws me an error, because it returns a `y` **per row** of x, and I cannot specify the first dimension of `x` because this number is variable.

How do I make tensorflow produce only 1 output vector **per set** of input (read all rows of x, and after make classification)? Do I have to add another dimension?

Comment: By variable number of rows, do you mean that you have a variable numbers of training/testing samples? Or that each of your samples is a Nx4 matrix with variable N?

Comment: Each sample is a Nx4 matrix with variable N

Comment: That is not going to work out of the box in tensorflow. I'm not an expert, so I might be wrong and there might be some alternatives, but tensorflow is intended to work (and works better) with fixed sized training data. You would have to preprocess all your data so that it has the same shape. In your case, the first `[None` in the shape of both `x` and `y` indicates that you have an arbitrary number of samples (unless you feed them 1by1). For an arbitrary number of cols you would need something like `[None, None, number_features]`, but I don't think that will work at all.

Comment: That's not my primary problem. I can slice the samples to an equal length for now. I have tried that, too, but it still returns N (N being the N rows in the Nx4 matrix) `y `s, one for each row of the sample. How do I only make it return a single `y`?

Comment: If you feed something `NxD` to tensorflow it will assume you have `N` samples of `D` features. Try reshaping the input to `(1, N*4)` (also for the tensors to be `None, N*4`).

Comment: I cannot help debug this without seeing the code where you're creating the samples and feeding the placeholders.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo That is the approach used in the MNIST tutorial, where all features were pixels. One of my features however, depends on another feature, i.e. feature 2 is dependent on feature 1. Hence if I unroll feature 1, the value of feature 1 will be duplicated many times. And the pairing between feature 1 and 2 would be lost, or? Is your suggested approach for data with features which theoretically depend on another?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos not sure what you mean, but the samples are a `[N, 4]` numpy arrays loaded from a file. Feeding the placeholders is this line?: `_, _, pred = sess.run([train_op, cross_entropy, output], {x: train_samples, y: one_hot_vector})`

Comment: Is the issue then that y does not have shape [N, 4]?